# Substract ranges between 2 tables in R

Tags: r

If I have:

df1:

```
  start end
     1   4
     5   7
     8  12
    20  22
```

and

df2:

```
  start end
     3   6
    10  15
```

How do I get a table that contains intervals of df1 that are not in df2 in R?

For example, the first row of df1 is `(1..4)` and since it overlaps with interval `(3..6)` in df2, I want `(1..4) - (3..6)` which is `(1..2)` (i.e. interval in the first row of df1 that is not in df2).

In the end, I want a result like this:

```
  start end
     1   2
     7   7
     8   9
    20  22
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of how df1 and df2 become your result.

Comment: so, one row of df1 has to be compared with all rows of df2??? what is meaning of *overlap* here?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you would want to do with an interval in df1 that completely encompasses an interval in df2 (like df1 ```10...15``` and df2 ```5...20```).

Comment: hi, there are prob 4 kinds of overlaps, i.e. range in df2 could be 1) within or 2) fully covering the range in df1 or 3) start in df1 falling within range in df2 or 4) end in df1 falling within range in df2. would like to show how you would want the output to look like in each case?

Answer (score 3):

We can create a sequence between `df2`'s `start` and `end` and store it in `vals`. For each row in `df1` we can then include `range` of only those values which are not present in `vals`.

```
vals <- unlist(Map(seq, df2$start, df2$end))
t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) range(setdiff(x[1]:x[2], vals))))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    7    7
#[3,]    8    9
#[4,]   20   22
```